# Create custom fields/meta data gender+country - radiobuttons and dropdown on register screen for these fields

Tags: custom-field, login, user-meta, dropdown, user-registration

On register I want the user to select gender (radio buttons) and a country (dropdown from list of countries) as well as an agreement checkbox. I'd also like all of these to be editable on the user profile. (I'm using thememylogin for the signup/edit process)

I can't find any help or tips anywhere on how to do this, even as a starting point or stepping stone.

I've tried custom field plugins but they either have features missing OR break the profile saving mechanism. A manual way of implementing these custom fields and also displaying them in login/register would also be helpful (plus would also like admin to be able to sort users by country etc.)

I don't understand why something so simple on paper should be so difficult to do, or let alone find information about.

Please help.
Thanks.

EDIT: My attempt at gender radiobox

```
  add_action( 'register_form', 'myplugin_register_form' );
  function myplugin_register_form() {



    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="first_name"><?php _e( 'First Name', 'mydomain' ) ?><br />
            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_unslash( $first_name ) ); ?>" size="25" /></label>
    </p>
        <p>
        <label for="last_name"><?php _e( 'Last Name', 'mydomain' ) ?><br />
            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_unslash( $last_name ) ); ?>" size="25" /></label>
    </p>
            <p>
            <label for="gender"><?php _e( 'Gender', 'mydomain' ) ?><br />
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_unslash( $gender ) ); ?>" size="25" /><?php _e( 'Male', 'mydomain' ) ?></br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_unslash( $gender ) ); ?>" size="25" /><?php _e( 'Female', 'mydomain' ) ?></label></p>
            <label for="description"><?php _e( 'Tell us a little about yourself!', 'mydomain' ) ?><br />
            <textarea cols="50" rows="4"" name="description" id="description" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_unslash( $description ) ); ?>" size="25"></textarea></label>
    </p>

    <?php
}


add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'myplugin_registration_errors', 10, 3 );
function myplugin_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {

    if ( empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) && trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) == '' ) {
        $errors->add( 'first_name_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must include a first name.', 'mydomain' ) );
    }
    if ( empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) && trim( $_POST['last_name'] ) == '' ) {
        $errors->add( 'last_name', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must include a last name.', 'mydomain' ) );
    }
    if ( empty( $_POST['gender'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['gender'] ) && trim( $_POST['gender'] ) == '' ) {
        $errors->add( 'gender', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must define a gender', 'mydomain' ) );
    }


    return $errors;
}


add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_user_register' );
function myplugin_user_register( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) );
    }
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', trim( $_POST['last_name'] ) );
    }
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['description'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'description', trim( $_POST['description'] ) );
    }
if ( ! empty( $_POST['gender'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'gender', trim( $_POST['gender'] ) );
    }   

}
```

Comment: What code did you write trying to implement it? (it is simple after all ;) )

Comment: Here's my attempt on gender/radio box selection based on some other code. Doesn't seem to recognise the selection... ?

Comment: What do you mean in "Doesn't seem to recognise the selection"

Comment: It will display the error message even when a box is checked. I think I may be doing the method all wrong anyway...

Comment: Its not something specific to TML plugin as it uses default WP hooks. There is already a thread on WP forum [Check here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-theme-my-login-adding-new-fields)

Comment: @timdaniels, this is simple html form handling..... have you checked what is the value in `$_POST['gender']`? have you inspected the HTML to see if you actual have a value in the radio buttons?

Comment: Yeah I'm an idiot.. a little research on form handling in PHP would have gone a long way.. not even a wordpress issue! - I figured it out now :)